# How to get USB ports information using C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, usb

As we know that we can use the terminal to find the USB ports by commanding lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:02d2 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 054c:0688 Sony Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 034: ID 13fe:4100 Kingston Technology Company Inc. Flash drive
Bus 003 Device 033: ID 2500:0020  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also went to the websites and had a lot of suggestions but they are kind of not working as the list which I expected above.

- [Getting USB Device path from USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19109522/getting-usb-device-path-from-usb-port)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61484/find-the-information-of-usb-devices-in-c
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/503928/missing-usb-h-file-what-is-it-where-do-i-get-it
- http://www.linux-usb.org/
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/

.... and so on.

I am trying to understand how to link USB input to the C++ but I am getting confuse and have no ideas with it.

Comment: `they are kind of not working` care to elaborate? Please [edit] in some addition context, like what _exactly_ is not working - with associated / relevant logs / console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, [the libusb library](http://libusb.info/) provides a C library API for using USB devices, that should be usable with C++ too. `libusb` is a part of all major Linux distributions.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik: I am sorry for the lacking of skills on C++. That would be nice if you can help me more details, I went on the link you provided, but there are a lot of files and seem not to help me to answer my question. And I thought that will be simple solution, but getting complicated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik: I went on that link and clicked onto the "you can also access the source directly from github.", then chose the "libusb" folder, there are bunches of files, so I confused.